# Python2.7, mkdir question. throw error : [WindowsError: [Error 3] : 'Y:\\'], but the path exists in PC

Tags: windows, python-2.7, mkdir, drive, mapped-drive

Code is simple as follows:

`os.mkdir("Y:\\DirName")`

throw error:

`WindowsError: [Error 3] : 'Y:\\'`

Error is **"Y:\\"**, not "Y:\\DirName". Y not a local disk, is a Network disk mapping. Use the Windows command 'mkdir' to succeed. Y drive can be accessed on the computer normally.
I want know What could be the cause of the error, please.

Comment: Mapped drives are local to a logon session. With UAC, the standard and elevated access tokens have separate logon sessions. There's a setting to link the creation of mapped drives in both logon sessions. In "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" add a DWORD named "EnableLinkedConnections" with the value 1. This policy applies to mapped drives created by `WNetUseConnectionW` or `NetUseAdd`, including mapped drives created by CMD's `pushd <unc path>` command. It does not apply to devices added by `DefineDosDeviceW` such as substitute drives created by subst.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the double slash? e.g. main C drive is `C:\` instead of `C:\\`

Comment: `'Y:\\DirName' == 'Y:\DirName' == r'Y:\DirName'` => `True`